# What factors affect ideal s3ql --max-obj-size value?

Tags: s3ql

I'm trying to understand all the relevant implications of the --max-obj-size value used when creating an [s3ql](https://github.com/s3ql/s3ql/) file system. I have yet to find a complete description of the implications of this option, but have been able to piece together a few bits from the docs and discussion groups.

Mainly, I have found reasons to use larger --max-obj-size values, which leaves me wondering, why not use an arbitrarily large value (10mb? 100mb? 1gb?):

- Smaller values mean more "inodes" are used, and worse performance from the sqlite database (as the same number of files requires more inode entries)
- Smaller values can hurt throughput (especially for [sequential reads](http://www.rath.org/s3ql-docs/tips.html#improving-copy-performance)).

From the version 1.8 [changelog](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!searchin/s3ql/block$20size/s3ql/vrUQpYvbOL0/SilCK40X01YJ):

> As a matter of fact, a small S3QL block size does *not* have any
> advantage over a large block size when storing lots of small
> files. A small block size, however, seriously degrades performance
> when storing larger files. This is because S3QL is effectively
> using a dynamic block size, and the --blocksize value merperformanceely
> specifies an upper limit.

So far the only advantages I have found or imagined for smaller block sizes are:

- Less bandwidth used to re-write a portion of a file
- Possibly better deduplication

> The --min-obj-size option does not affect deduplication. Deduplication
> happens before blocks are grouped.

> The --max-obj-size affects deduplication, since it implicitly determines
> the maximum size of a block.

Found [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!searchin/s3ql/block$20size/s3ql/7inpyQYUEf8/WmuelaF70AEJ):

Can anyone offer a summary of the trade-offs one makes when selecting a larger or smaller --max-obj-size when creating a s3ql file system?